# Restoring the Sms Contents?

Tags: android, sms, restore

I've take SMS Backup using their URI `content://sms/inbox` with this method Uri.getHost().

And, i've changed this to File format using [this](http://pastebin.com/FyY2hJDp) .

Now, i need to restore this contents to their Database properly. What type of method will i use? Anyone guide me. This will very useful for me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code for inserting into the SMS content Provider :

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("address", "9953834074111");
initialValues.put("date", "1308281011976");
initialValues.put("body", "Body of this");
initialValues.put("type", "1");
getContentResolver().insert(smsuri, initialValues);
```

Check it whether inserted it or not bu using :

```
    Cursor cursor1 =  getContentResolver().query(smsuri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if((cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("address"))).equalsIgnoreCase("9953834074111")){
                String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("address"));
                String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("date"));
                String body = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("type"));
                Log.v("address",address);
                Log.v("date",date);
                Log.v("body",body);
                Log.v("type",type);
            }
        } while (cursor1.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Venky  I used your code to store some values, I get this as new message in inbox but for only one value. When I loop through various values I don't get even a single one.